# Automatically inferred generic type in trait

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance

I want a generic base class which can be mixed in some traits.

Is it possible to have the mixins automatically adopt the generic type of the base class?

```
abstract class Base[T] {
  def foo: T = ???
  def bar(value: T): Boolean
}

trait MixinA {
  self: Base[U] => // U should be automatically bound to T of Base[T]
  def bar(value: U): Boolean = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something approaching this using an abstract type in `Base`:

```
abstract class Base[T] {
  type U <: T
  def foo: U = ???
  def bar(value: U): Boolean
}

trait MixinA {
  self: Base[_] =>
  final def bar(value: U): Boolean = false
}
```

REPL test:

```
scala> class Impl extends Base[Int] with MixinA
defined class Impl

scala> val i = new Impl
i: Impl = Impl@7ca5cc9e

scala> val x: Int = i.foo
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  at Base.foo(<console>:9)
  ... 33 elided
```

As you can see the compiler correctly determined that `i.foo` is a sub-type of `Int` (concretely, it **is** `Int`) and thus can be assigned to `x` (the exception here is just because you have left its body unimplemented).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need `U` to be a type parameter of your `MixinA`.

```
trait MixinA[U] { self: Base[U] => ...
```

Type parameters are in a way like function parameters, if they are declared you need to pass them from somewhere (no magic).

Comment: I want to avoid having to specify the generic type explicitly for the mixin again:
`new Base[Int] with MixinA` rather than `new Base[Int] with MixinA[Int]`

Comment: Having the type parameter `U` in `MixinA` is required so that it can work with appropriatly parametrized base trait. Otherwise use type member.